# Compare a Part of the date using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to compare, using LINQ, a date string `"2010-06-11"` with a field value in the database `"2013-07-25 14:33:58.070"`, but only the year-month-day part.

I tried this:

```
updateDate = "2010-06-11";

_adRepository.Query.Where(p => p.DateModified.ToString("YYYYMMDD") <= updateDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

but it's not working, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: Can't compare strings like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems not mentioned earlier is that the test data you're using will always fail to return a value. "2013-07-25" will never be less than "2010-06-11".

That being said, your code really should be converting the updateDate variable into a date time and doing the comparison against that rather than converting the DateModifed field in the table. Otherwise the conversion is applied against all of the records in the database. The code I would use is:

```
var updateDateString = "2010-06-11";
DateTime updateDate;

if (DateTime.TryParse(updateDateString, out updateDate))
{
    _adRepository.Query.Where(p => p.DateModified <= updateDate).FirstOrDefault();
}
else
{
     // throw an exception or something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`_adRepository.Query.Where(p => p.DateModified.Day <= DateTime.Parse(updateDate).Day);`

It might have some issues with parse, but I can't remember proper format for it.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I get Exception:Thrown: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." (System.NotSupportedException)

Answer (score 0):

Date format is incorrect.  You want "yyyyMMdd".  But this is trying to get linq to do a string compare.  If you are using EF it probably won't work.

Convert UpdateDate to a DateTime instead and use that in your query.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DateTime updateDate = DateTime.Today;
_adRepository.Query.Where(p => p.DateModified.Date <= updateDate).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from q in _adRepository.Query
where DateTime.Compare(updateDate.Date, DateTime.Parse(q.DateModified).Date) <= 0
select q
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in LinqPad

```
DateTime[] update = new DateTime[]{ new DateTime(2014,01,01), new DateTime(2014,01,29), new DateTime(2014,01,22)};

var selected = update.Where(x => x.Date <= new DateTime(2014,01,22).Date);
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but how can I map the date with my updateDate var?

Comment: You mean this part {updateDate = "2010-06-11";}  Datetime Update = Convert.ToDateTime(updateDate)... to get the Datetime form the string